# How to get all keys from properties file?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am working on spring boot application ,I have one property file ,I am reading property file like below

```
     @Configuration
     @ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:mail.properties", prefix = "mail")
     public class MailConfiguration {

       public static class Smtp {
        private boolean auth;
         private boolean starttlsEnable;

           // ... getters and setters
         }

      @NotBlank
     private String host;
     private int port;  
     private String from;
     private String username;
      ..............
  }
```

**Mail .properites**

```
mail.host=localhost
mail.port=25
mail.smtp.auth=false
mail.smtp.starttls-enable=false
mail.from=me@localhost
```

This working fine ,But Instead of reading one by one property , I want to get all property keys from properties file ,How can I get this .

Comment: What output do you expect? can you provide an example?

Comment: `@ConfigurationProperties` is intended to provide type-safe binding of the properties. Accessing all of the keys (and presumably the values) rather defeats the purpose of using `@ConfigurationProperties`. Could you describe what you're trying to do? There might well be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Map for that. Something like: (its "pseudo-code" - may contain spelling mistakes or something, just to show You the idea)

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:mail.properties", prefix = "mail")
public static class MailConfiguration {

    private Map<String, Object> mail = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public Map<String, Object> getMail() {
        return this.mail;
    }
}
```

Should do the work.

Regards,